# Clojure mapping over strings

Tags: string, dictionary, clojure, higher-order-functions

I'm stumped in Clojure. I'm trying to write a system that transforms certain characters of a string based on simple rules that are encoded in pairs like this : ["A" "B"] is a rule to turn "A" into "B"

I have a function "apply-rules-to-char" which takes a vector of such rules and a char, finds the first rule that matches and applies it. It seems to work

```
(apply-rules-to-char [["A" "B"]] "C")  produces "C"
(apply-rules-to-char [["A" "B"]] "A")  produces "B"
(apply-rules-to-char [["A" "B"]] "M")  produces "M"
```

However when I now try to apply this across a string, using map

```
(map (partial apply-rules-to-char [["A" "B"]]) "CAM")
```

I get back

```
(\C \A \M)
```

In other words, it's run through the string "CAM" but hasn't done the transformation on the "A".

Can anyone explain why this is?

Update: Here's the definition of apply-rules-to-char. I'd guess it's not relevant because it always performs correctly when tested by itself. It's only in the map that it fails.

```
(defn apply-rules-to-char [rules c]
  (let [rule (first (filter #(applicable % c) rules))]
    (if (nil? rule) c (apply-rule-to-char rule c) )  ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `apply-rules-to-char` function appears to want a string (e.g. `"A"`), not a character (e.g. `\A`), which is what a string is made up of. In other words, your function needs to be able to work as `(apply-rules-to-char [["A" "B"]] \A)`, because that's what it will get from `map`.

Comment: Ah .. so single characters aren't equal to strings of length 1?

Comment: @interstar: Nope. Character is a distinct type from String.